# set img src from already loaded to browser src without querying a host for this again with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, clone

I want to change an img src with jquery, without pulling an image from server again.

I do it with next chunk of code:

```
  var img = $(this).find('img');
  $('#preview .modal-body img').prop('src',img.prop('src'));
  $('#preview').modal();
```

But browser is trying to pull this image from a server again. 
how i can avoid  it ?

Comment: If the src is the same, and assuming you have set your headers correctly, it won't go back to the server - it should hit your browser cache instead

Comment: it touches a server about last modified header. and uses cache if not modified.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can replaceWith  I havent tested...

```
var img = $(this).find('img');
$('#preview .modal-body img').replaceWith(img);
$('#preview').modal();
```

Comment: but replace with is removes old element. my task doesn't need that

Comment: your task needs to access an image without an HTTP request.. this should do it.

Comment: but i don't need to remove the original img